# How to distinguish total return and absolute return funds in the KIID

Tags: risk-management, mutual-fund

I hope this question is on-topic. It is not relally a quant question but it is a question that quants in risk management in asset management firms have to answer:

In the KIID (key investor information document) directive investment funds have to be categorized as market funds, life-cycle funds, structured funds, total return and absolute return funds (see an ESMA paper [here](http://www.esma.europa.eu/system/files/10_673.pdf)) in order to decide about the methodology to calculate the SRRI (synthetic risk reward indicator).

The difference between an absolute return fund and a total return fund is hard to tell in practice. Which are your strongest arguments/relevant traits of the fund that you use to decide?

How would you categorize: a multi asset class (stocks, bonds) momentum strategy - how  a multi asset class risk parity strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Absolute Return is from pure price appreciation, Total Return includes all related asset cashflows (dividends, coupons etc.) aswell.

According to the ESMA document, it has nothing to do with that: A Total Return Fund is a fund with a return target to be achieved at smallest possible (but unbounded) risk, an Absolute Return Fund has a Risk (VaR) limit under which the return is maximized.

A momentum strategy is long-short for maximum return, so its Total Return Fund.

A risk parity strategy defines a maximum risk level, under which the portfolio is then optimized for maximum return, so its Absolute Return Fund.

Comment: Thanks for your interpretation. I wait for more answers and comments.